Windows 11 - How to customise CSS in MS-Store Firefox; or otherwise set a non-MS Store app as default by protocol
I recently upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11 (fresh installation). I'm in the process of re-customising all my settings. However, I have not yet found a way to customise Firefox, which is my preferred browser.
On Windows 10, I used Firefox Portable. I like portable applications, because they run stand-alone, regardless of installation status. I saved the Firefox Portable folder separately, and can run the program with no issue under Windows 11.
However, the problem is when it comes to the Windows default application. There appears to be no way to set a non-Microsoft Store application as the default app for a protocol. You can do it by file type, and I can set .htm[l] files to open with Firefox Portable. But I want to set http and https protocols to open with Firefox Portable by default, and I can see no way of doing this. I have found this page where it is discussed:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/non-store-default-apps-for-a-file-protocol-in/2077cbe0-800c-4eba-9990-4985429dd7a7
The alternate option is to use the Microsoft Store version of Firefox, which I can do. However, I can see no way of customising the UI to my liking. I use UserChrome.css with highly customised CSS in the Portable version of Firefox. But I can't find where to put this with the MS-Store version of Firefox.
So my question is two-fold. Either I need a way to assign a non-MS Store app to a protocol; or I need to know where to put the .css file in the MS-Store version of Firefox.
I was about to post this question on Stack Overflow, but then decided it would probably be a better fit here.

“There appears to be no way to set a non-Microsoft Store application as the default app for a protocol.”—This is of course not correct. A regularly installed Firefox works perfectly fine as the default browser. No Microsoft Store involved. IMHO the solution is to just not use the portable version. Though it must be possible to make it work either way.

@DanielB - It didn't occur to me to do this. Thanks. I will try it when home.

Although the question remains whether I would be able to set the non-MS Store version of Firefox as the default for the http[s] protocol.

You've been able to do so for decades (how browsers worked before MS Store), and they have never removed the capability after introducing Store either. The problem isn't with Store, it's with Portable apps not adding themselves to the right place in the Registry (which is by design of a Portable app, after all) – the official Firefox installer knows how to do that. (I'm like 70% sure you could do it for any .exe by hand, or using Nirsoft tools, as URL scheme associations use more-or-less the same system as for file type associations, but at the moment can't write a proper answer.)

You can try registering a portable Firefox installation as your default browser using RegPortBro or SetUserFTA 2. Christoph Kolbicz is the foremost authority on file type and scheme associations in Windows.
